# VS 2017 + ASP.Net Core + Angular 4 cant build

Tags: asp.net, angular

i create a blank new ASP.Net Core with Angular from VS 2017 (in my Document folder) and i try to build it i always get this error:
[VS2017 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnFE4.png)

If i create a blank new asp.net without Angular it works fine.

It somehow has a error with the cmd.exe but i cant figure out why. The path to the cmd.exe is correct, launched VS with administrator privileges, notejs is installed, opening the .cspoj Line 33 (output TaskParameter...) and executing the command works too.

```
<Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
</Exec>
```

Comment: Could you please translate  the visual studio error message in english?

Comment: First of all, **never** post an [image of an exception](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). Second, please post your exception details in english. StackOverflow is an english-only site and german exception details will mean nothing to anyone.

Comment: "The path for the executedable file of the Task C:Windows\system32\cmd.exe is not valid" or smth similar to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing the following command manually in the CMD (from the .csproj) the error didnt come anymore while building, rebuilding.

```
 <Target Name="DebugRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('wwwroot\dist') ">
    ....

    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js" />
  </Target>
```