# ASP.NET Core with Angular Template given by Microsoft VS ASP.NET CORE WITH ANGULAR CLI

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, single-page-application

I got the same issue describe here - [VS 2017 + ASP.Net Core + Angular 4 cant build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035705/vs-2017-asp-net-core-angular-4-cant-build)

But I have different Questions.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Angular Template. 
I Created New Project and I have added one Variable in Counter Component like below and I have Re-Build the Code and ran it from Visual Studio.

```
export class CounterComponent {
public currentCount = 0;

public incrementCounter() {

    var FirstVariable = "aaaa";
    debugger;
    this.currentCount++;
}
```

}

Then I have added One more Variable 
as

```
var SecondVariable = "aaaa";
```

But When I REBUILD the Solution, This Changes are not appeared in Code when I checked by pressing F12 in Google Chrome.

As per the Link, Pasted above - I ran this command

```
node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
```

and then I can able to see the Changes.

So My Question is Which Template is the BEST?

Microsoft Asp.NET CORE with Angular template provided by Microsoft

OR

Will it be good to go with ANGULAR CLI + ASP.NET CORE??? 
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1208529/Angular-CLI-and-ASP-NET-Core-Angular-Template

WHY We should go with the Angular Template given by Asp.net core, Is there any advantage??? Its not even Building the Code properly... Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this template [AspNetCoreSpa](https://github.com/asadsahi/AspNetCoreSpa) as it provides a full ready to use template, with data access, built-in security, swagger for API doc, tests, Docker, etc.

There's a nice community around this project and the dev is very reactive.

The architecture is clean and you can easily add or removes features.

You can see the template running [here](https://aspnetcorespa.azurewebsites.net/).